# Pass boolean array without copying with `f2py`?

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, f2py

How should Fortran variables be typed if I intend to pass them a boolean, NumPy array with `f2py`? I have tried both `integer*1` and `logical*1`, but these both indicate that the array is copied.

For example, if I compile the file, `foo.f95`, containing:

```
subroutine foo(x, n)
    logical*1 x(n)
    !f2py intent(in) x
    !f2py intent(hide), depend(x) :: n=shape(x,0)
    ...
end subroutine
```

with `f2py -c -m foo foo.f90 -DF2PY_REPORT_ON_ARRAY_COPY=1` and run something like:

```
import numpy as np
import foo
x = np.random.randn(100) < 0
foo.foo(x)
```

it prints

```
copied an array: size=100, elsize=1
```

I get the same result if I change `logical*1` to `integer*1`. What is the proper type for the boolean array in the Fortran file, so that the array is not copied?

Note that this is not a problem of memory contiguity since the arrays are 1D -- `foo.foo(np.asfortranarray(x))` prints the same copy message.

Comment: [This fortran 95 guide](http://northstar-www.dartmouth.edu/doc/solaris-forte/manuals/fortran/user_guide/C_f95.html) says that `logical*1` is a one byte logical type. Using `logical` gives the same message.

Comment: Well, the guy is not a standard document. francescalus is right, the `*` syntax is standard only for character types. But probably it wont change much.

Comment: Alternatively using C instead of Fortran, one can employ [`ctypes`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5868051/1430829) and set the respective return argument type to `numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer(ctypes.c_bool)`.

Comment: That can be done with Fortran the same way. Use `logical(c_bool)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From some experiments(*), it seems that Python/f2py treats `np.int8` as compatible with `logical*1`, while `np.bool` or `np.bool8` not for some reason. After inserting `print *, "(fort) x = ", x` into foo.f90, we get:

```
>>> foo.foo( np.array( [ True, False, False ], dtype=np.bool ) )
copied an array: size=3, elsize=1
 (fort) x =  T F F
>>> foo.foo( np.array( [ False, True, False ], dtype=np.bool8 ) )
copied an array: size=3, elsize=1
 (fort) x =  F T F
>>> foo.foo( np.array( [ False, False, True ], dtype=np.int8 ) ) # no copy
 (fort) x =  F F T
```

Because `True` and `False` are simply mapped to 1 and 0, using an `int8` array on the Python side may be convenient.

---

(*) Some experiments

Here, I changed the f2py intent comment to `inout` to see whether we can modify the array from the Fortran side.

foo.f90:

```
subroutine foo(x, n)
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    integer n
    logical*1 x( n )
    ! logical x( n )
    ! logical(c_bool) x( n )

    !f2py intent(inout) x
    !f2py intent(hide), depend(x) :: n=shape(x,0)

    print *, "(fort) x = ", x
    print *, "(fort) sizeof(x(1)) = ", sizeof(x(1))
    print *, "(fort) resetting x(:) to true"
    x(:) = .true.
end subroutine
```

test.py:

```
import numpy as np
import foo

for T in [ np.bool, np.bool8,
           np.int,  np.int8,  np.int32,  np.int64,
           np.uint, np.uint8, np.uint32, np.uint64,
           np.dtype('b'), np.dtype('int8'), np.dtype('int32') ]:

    print( "-------------------------" )
    print( "dtype =", T )

    x = np.array( [ True, False, True ], dtype=T )
    print( "input x =", x )

    try:
        foo.foo( x )
        print( "output x =", x )
    except:
        print( "failed" )
```

Results with `logical*1`:

```
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'bool'>
input x = [ True False  True]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'numpy.bool_'>
input x = [ True False  True]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'int'>
input x = [1 0 1]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'numpy.int8'>
input x = [1 0 1]
 (fort) x =  T F T
 (fort) sizeof(x(1)) =                     1
 (fort) resetting x(:) to true
output x = [1 1 1]
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'numpy.int32'>
input x = [1 0 1]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'numpy.int64'>
input x = [1 0 1]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'numpy.uint64'>
input x = [1 0 1]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'numpy.uint8'>
input x = [1 0 1]
 (fort) x =  T F T
 (fort) sizeof(x(1)) =                     1
 (fort) resetting x(:) to true
output x = [1 1 1]
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'numpy.uint32'>
input x = [1 0 1]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'numpy.uint64'>
input x = [1 0 1]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = int8
input x = [1 0 1]
 (fort) x =  T F T
 (fort) sizeof(x(1)) =                     1
 (fort) resetting x(:) to true
output x = [1 1 1]
-------------------------
dtype = int8
input x = [1 0 1]
 (fort) x =  T F T
 (fort) sizeof(x(1)) =                     1
 (fort) resetting x(:) to true
output x = [1 1 1]
-------------------------
dtype = int32
input x = [1 0 1]
failed
```

Results with `logical` (default kind):

```
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'bool'>
input x = [ True False  True]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'numpy.bool_'>
input x = [ True False  True]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'int'>
input x = [1 0 1]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'numpy.int8'>
input x = [1 0 1]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'numpy.int32'>
input x = [1 0 1]
 (fort) x =  T F T
 (fort) sizeof(x(1)) =                     4
 (fort) resetting x(:) to true
output x = [1 1 1]
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'numpy.int64'>
input x = [1 0 1]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'numpy.uint64'>
input x = [1 0 1]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'numpy.uint8'>
input x = [1 0 1]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'numpy.uint32'>
input x = [1 0 1]
 (fort) x =  T F T
 (fort) sizeof(x(1)) =                     4
 (fort) resetting x(:) to true
output x = [1 1 1]
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'numpy.uint64'>
input x = [1 0 1]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = int8
input x = [1 0 1]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = int8
input x = [1 0 1]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = int32
input x = [1 0 1]
 (fort) x =  T F T
 (fort) sizeof(x(1)) =                     4
 (fort) resetting x(:) to true
output x = [1 1 1]
```

Results with `logical(c_bool)` (via iso_c_binding):

```
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'bool'>
input x = [ True False  True]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'numpy.bool_'>
input x = [ True False  True]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'int'>
input x = [1 0 1]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'numpy.int8'>
input x = [1 0 1]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'numpy.int32'>
input x = [1 0 1]
 (fort) x =  T F F
 (fort) sizeof(x(1)) =                     1
 (fort) resetting x(:) to true
output x = [65793     0     1]
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'numpy.int64'>
input x = [1 0 1]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'numpy.uint64'>
input x = [1 0 1]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'numpy.uint8'>
input x = [1 0 1]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'numpy.uint32'>
input x = [1 0 1]
 (fort) x =  T F F
 (fort) sizeof(x(1)) =                     1
 (fort) resetting x(:) to true
output x = [65793     0     1]
-------------------------
dtype = <class 'numpy.uint64'>
input x = [1 0 1]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = int8
input x = [1 0 1]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = int8
input x = [1 0 1]
failed
-------------------------
dtype = int32
input x = [1 0 1]
 (fort) x =  T F F
 (fort) sizeof(x(1)) =                     1
 (fort) resetting x(:) to true
output x = [65793     0     1]
```

For some reason, this last `logical(c_bool)` does not work with the above usage... (f2py seems to consider `logical(c_bool)` as 4 bytes, while gfortran treats it as 1 byte, so something is inconsistent...)

Comment: Hmm. I think that I will simply work with `int` type on both ends!